# How do I set the time zones in order to correct mismatched Timestamps for MySQL and PHP?

Tags: joomla, error, timezone, timestamp

I currently have a warning on Environment settings. Timestamps reported by MySQL and PHP are mismatched.

Answer (score 6):

The warning is because the timezone of the server does not match with the timezone set in MySQL. We had similar warning and after setting the timezone in both Centos & MySQL, the warning is not displayed anymore.

## Additional Info:

This is how we corrected/fixed the timezones, if it helps. The below instructions are for setting timezone to GMT, you need to use your timezone if you want to use the below instructions.

**Setting the timezone in CentOS**

Check the date and timezone

```
[root@my-server ~]# date
Mon Nov 24 10:27:14 CET 2014
```

The above is incorrect. We need to set GMT for Europe/London

Fix the timezone

```
[root@my-server ~]# rm /etc/localtime
[root@my-server ~]# ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London /etc/localtime
```

Now check the date and timezone again

```
[root@my-server ~]# date
Mon Nov 24 09:30:14 GMT 2014
```

**Setting the timezone in MySQL**

Check the timezone in MySQL

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone;
+-----------------------------+
| @@global.time_zone          |
+-----------------------------+
| SYSTEM                      |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Set timezone '+00:00' for GMT

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+00:00';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Now check the timezone again in MysSQL

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone;
+-----------------------------+
| @@global.time_zone          |
+-----------------------------+
| +00:00                      |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3):

In my experience with this, you can modify the default timezone setting for your CMS. Not sure how to do this in Joomla, but there are UI options for this in both Wordpress and Drupal so I would imagine that Joomla offers a similar setting.

Comment: Yep, I just had a Wordpress site giving this error -- it didn't have the timezone set in the Wordpress admin UI.